# Does section break=^b has charcode in MS Word VBA? [ not page break=^m=chr(12) ]

Tags: vba, ms-word

'update'

(I am not native English speaker)

In MS Word,

**find and replace dialog** can find both **page break=^m** and **section break=^b**.

But in VBA,

**Selection.Extend** can perform with **chr(12)** (=^m), but can't perform with **^b** or **^m**.

I need using **Selection.Extend** to perform some task with **section break**.

Does **section break=^b** has charcode in MS Word VBA?

Comment: You may get more help if you explain why you must use selection.extend. I do not know if there is a chr() equivalent to ^. You can certainly cycle through word sections. activedocument.sections.

Comment: I just want to delete content from the cursor to end of section, not including section break mark. ‘Selection.extend character’ just fit my need if I have the char code of ^b.

But I also have a workaround. Using ‘Selection.MoveEnd unit:=wdSection, count:=1’ can select content from the cursor to end of section, including section break mark. I just need to minus a character from the end of the selection range. Then delete the selection. Thanks for your reply.
@CharlesKenyon

Answer (score 0):

From your comments ...

> I just want to delete content from the cursor to end of section, not
> including section break mark.

```
Dim oSec As Section
'you'll obviously have another method of specifying the section object
Set oSec = ActiveDocument.Content.Sections(1)

With Selection
    ' subtracting 1 from oSec.Range.End excludes
    ' the Chr(12) section break character from the selection
    .MoveEnd wdCharacter, oSec.Range.End - 1 - .End
    .Delete
End With
```